# Lodash How to verify if a property are all equal in array if I don't have the property to exclude

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

let's say I have this aray of employee data

```
var service = [{
        AssignedEmployeeInternalID: "8000000011",
        AssignedEmployeeUUID: "00000000-0001-1EE1-82C1-8379F1C4462E",
        BillableIndicator: true,
        BusinessPartnerFormattedName: "Sébastien Brun",
        EndDateTime: null,
        EndDatetimeZoneCode: "UTC",
        Info: "-N/A",
        InternalID: "",
        ObjectID: "00163E0E46241EE988E20C5E4033E0BE",
        ParentObjectID: "00163E0306801ED287F1C8E9CDFA9E4A",
        PeriodPlansArray: [],
        PlannedWorkQuantity: "0.00000000000000",
        PlannedWorkQuantityunitCode: "HUR",
        PlannedWorkQuantityunitCodeText: "",

    },
    {
        AssignedEmployeeInternalID: "8000000011",
        AssignedEmployeeUUID: "00000000-0001-1EE1-82C1-8379F1C4462E",
        BillableIndicator: false,
        BusinessPartnerFormattedName: "Sébastien Brun",
        EndDateTime: null,
        EndDatetimeZoneCode: "UTC",
        Info: "-N/A",
        InternalID: "",
        ObjectID: "00163E0E46241EE988E20C5E4033E0BE",
        ParentObjectID: "00163E0306801ED287F1C8E9CDFA9E4A",
        PeriodPlansArray: [],
        PlannedWorkQuantity: "0.00000000000000",
        PlannedWorkQuantityunitCode: "HUR",
        PlannedWorkQuantityunitCodeText: "",

    },
    {
        AssignedEmployeeInternalID: "8000000011",
        AssignedEmployeeUUID: "00000000-0001-1EE1-82C1-8379F1C4462E",
        BillableIndicator: true,
        BusinessPartnerFormattedName: "Sébastien Brun",
        EndDateTime: null,
        EndDatetimeZoneCode: "UTC",
        Info: "-N/A",
        InternalID: "",
        ObjectID: "00163E0E46241EE988E20C5E4033E0BE",
        ParentObjectID: "00163E0306801ED287F1C8E9CDFA9E4A",
        PeriodPlansArray: [],
        PlannedWorkQuantity: "0.00000000000000",
        PlannedWorkQuantityunitCode: "HUR",
        PlannedWorkQuantityunitCodeText: "",
    }
]
```

How to verify that `AssignedEmployeeInternalID` is the same in all the array ?

so far I came up with this  :

```
result =  _.differenceBy(service, [{ 'AssignedEmployeeInternalID': "8000000011" }], 'AssignedEmployeeInternalID');
```

but what if I don't have the value to exclude (I can't know in advance the AssignedEmployeeInternalID value )

I want to dynamically verify that the property are all the same

Comment: `var result = new Set(service.map(s => s['AssignedEmployeeInternalID'])).size === 1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `uniqBy` (see documentation https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniqBy) and then if the `length` of the resulting array is `1`, all array items have the same value for `AssignedEmployeeInternalID`:

```js
var uniqueByID = _.uniqBy(service, 'AssignedEmployeeInternalID');
var allMatch = uniqueByID.length === 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this in vanilla JavaScript if you use the Array `every` method as follows:

```js
var service = [{
        AssignedEmployeeInternalID: "8000000011",
        AssignedEmployeeUUID: "00000000-0001-1EE1-82C1-8379F1C4462E",
        BillableIndicator: true,
        BusinessPartnerFormattedName: "Sébastien Brun",
        EndDateTime: null,
        EndDatetimeZoneCode: "UTC",
        Info: "-N/A",
        InternalID: "",
        ObjectID: "00163E0E46241EE988E20C5E4033E0BE",
        ParentObjectID: "00163E0306801ED287F1C8E9CDFA9E4A",
        PeriodPlansArray: [],
        PlannedWorkQuantity: "0.00000000000000",
        PlannedWorkQuantityunitCode: "HUR",
        PlannedWorkQuantityunitCodeText: "",

    },
    {
        AssignedEmployeeInternalID: "8000000011",
        AssignedEmployeeUUID: "00000000-0001-1EE1-82C1-8379F1C4462E",
        BillableIndicator: false,
        BusinessPartnerFormattedName: "Sébastien Brun",
        EndDateTime: null,
        EndDatetimeZoneCode: "UTC",
        Info: "-N/A",
        InternalID: "",
        ObjectID: "00163E0E46241EE988E20C5E4033E0BE",
        ParentObjectID: "00163E0306801ED287F1C8E9CDFA9E4A",
        PeriodPlansArray: [],
        PlannedWorkQuantity: "0.00000000000000",
        PlannedWorkQuantityunitCode: "HUR",
        PlannedWorkQuantityunitCodeText: "",

    },
    {
        AssignedEmployeeInternalID: "8000000011",
        AssignedEmployeeUUID: "00000000-0001-1EE1-82C1-8379F1C4462E",
        BillableIndicator: true,
        BusinessPartnerFormattedName: "Sébastien Brun",
        EndDateTime: null,
        EndDatetimeZoneCode: "UTC",
        Info: "-N/A",
        InternalID: "",
        ObjectID: "00163E0E46241EE988E20C5E4033E0BE",
        ParentObjectID: "00163E0306801ED287F1C8E9CDFA9E4A",
        PeriodPlansArray: [],
        PlannedWorkQuantity: "0.00000000000000",
        PlannedWorkQuantityunitCode: "HUR",
        PlannedWorkQuantityunitCodeText: "",
    }
];

const theSame = service.every(el => el.AssignedEmployeeInternalID === service[0].AssignedEmployeeInternalID);

console.log(theSame);
```

Comment: We haven't integrated VanillaJS in our project "YET" but thank you for your answer !

Comment: @napi15 Sorry, I should have been more clear, vanilla JS is a term that means "regular JS"

Comment: Oh! I thought you were referring to this library : http://vanilla-js.com/ , it's crazy these days, new JS libraries comes up every day or so

Comment: Yeah, that website is actually a joke site